# BeautifulSoup find tags based on source position

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to find all of the tags in an html document whose text falls within a certain offset, say `100:200`.  This offset is an offset into the original HTML file, so if I do `f.read()[100:200]` this represents the piece of text I am looking for.  BeautifulSoup gets me part of the way there, as for each tag I can get its start with `tag.sourcepos`.  Using this, I could get the element closest to the start of the sequence.  However I am not sure how to line up the original offset with the offset into the element's text.  Perhaps if I could get the length of the `tag` itself, I could use that but I don't see any way of doing that.

Here a minimal attempt, where the second assert fails:

```
<html><head><title></title></head><body><span style="white-space: pre; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier;"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>AAA<br><br><br><br><br></span></body></html>
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('test.htm') as f:
    doc_content = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_content, 'html5lib')

spans = soup.find_all('span')

start = 137
end = 140
found = doc_content[start:end]
print(found)
assert found == 'AAA'

# Find first span before target start
best_span = max(s for s in spans if s.sourcepos < start)
offset = best_span.sourcepos + 1
breakpoint()
found = best_span.encode_contents()[start-offset:end-offset]
found = found.decode('utf8')
print(found)
assert(found == 'AAA')
```

The root cause seems to be that BS4 is 'helping' by inserting slashes into the `<br>` which were not originally there, corrupting the offset.

Comment: Can you add part of the HTML file, and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: "I want to find all of the tags in an html document whose text falls within a certain offset". Can you clearify what you want? What's the "text of tag"? Does it include the open and closing tags of the element? Or just the html content? Or just the Tag.text (children tags excluded)?

Comment: I can't help you if you don't clarify the problem. Probably you already know it, but `sourcepos` it's the position of the start tag relative to the the source line. Do you remove all the "\n" before defining the range?

Comment: just Tag.text, so not including children tags.  In this case the document is just a single line, though it would have to be fixed for multi-line documents.

Comment: Must Tag.text be *entirely* inside the range?

Comment: Did you consider thatTag.text in bs4 is the concatenation of all children tags? Are you interested only at text node(s) that are direct children of the Tag?

Answer (score 0):

> The root cause seems to be that BS4 is 'helping' by inserting slashes into the 
>  which were not originally there, corrupting the offset.

You can stop this by using the `formatter='html5'` argument for `encode_contents()`. See the [documentation - Output formatters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters).

Your 2nd assertion passes when you change this line:

```py
found = best_span.encode_contents()[start-offset:end-offset]
```

to this:

```py
found = best_span.encode_contents(formatter='html5')[start-offset:end-offset]
```

Though you really want splice a `str`, not `bytes`. It takes more than 1 byte to encode some utf-8 *code points*. You will end up chopping off a *code unit*, resulting in a malformed utf-8 sequence. So you want to move that to the next line:

```py
found = best_span.encode_contents(formatter='html5')
found = found.decode('utf8')[start-offset:end-offset]
```

In this particular case, it works. But when you set `formatter` as `html5`, certain characters will be encoded as [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML), so the output might be different to the input. Your original start and end offsets could be off.

If your html isn't perfectly-formed, the parser will try to fix it, so the output won't be the same as the input. See the [documentation - Differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

For these 2 reasons, you should parse the original html, output it, and then parse *that* output. That way the input should always be the same as the output.

```py
with open('test.htm') as f:
    doc_content = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_content, 'html5lib')
    doc_content = soup.encode_contents(formatter='html5').decode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_content, 'html5lib')
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong you simply want tags from any HTML file. If yes then you can simply use regex in Python. Here's a code for that

```
import re
html_code='''<html><head><title></title></head><body><span style="white-space: pre; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier;"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>AAA<br><br><br><br><br></span></body></html>'''
tags = re.findall(r'<[^>]+>', html_code)
for tag in tags:
    if ' 'in tag:
        tag_without_att = tag.split(' ')[0]+'>'
    else:
        tag_without_att = re.sub(r'\s?\w+=\"[\w\d]+\"', '', tag)
    print(tag_without_att)
```

Comment: Are there still people who haven’t read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3840170?

Comment: @user3840170 but my code works perfectly fine with his example code